# Setup a second router to add a new subnet

Tags: networking, router

[Image description of how it is setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDzp2.png)

First Router is in 192.168.1.x series.

Second router is set up in 192.168.0.x series

The second router is setup in router mode, DHCP Forwarder.
WAN IP address on second router is setup with an IP in 192.168.1.x series.

The users connected to second router with say IP 192.168.0.200, were not able to access internet.

**Edit:**
The second router was needed since there are only limited IP addresses available from the First router and I do not have access to First router.

What are the options for me to extend the IP range without having to change something in the First router.

**Edit 2:**
I think there was a slight confusion in the image I put through. Router 1 has internet access, router 2 is the extender.
Router 2's wan port is connected to router 1's lan port.
Router 2 WAN IP is configured as one IP from Router 1's series.

**Edit 3:**
Added port forwarding options available on my router[Port Forwarding options on my router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcu9G.png)

Comment: Is there a question? Why do you need a second router? Can't you set up two subnets on the first router since that what routers do; they connect multiple subnets?

Comment: @Andrews  Further to what Ron says, most times this setup is seen on SU it is usually the case that the second subnet is not needed, but what is needed is a second wifi access point.  The answer to this question is probably that you need NAT on router 2 or a static route on router 1, but perhaps first explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Second router was added since I dont have access to First router.
And the number of IP addresses available in First router is limited.

Comment: Somehow, you will need to let the first router know about the subnet on the second router, otherwise it won't know to send traffic to the second router for the new subnet. This is accomplished with either static routes or a common routing protocol between the two routers.

Comment: @Andrews Thanks for clarifying.  Your setup should work, you will just need to make sure NAT is enabled on router 2.  This is because router 1 does not know where 192.168.1.x is.  Normally you would make a route change on router 1 to tell it, but in this case you'll need to NAT everything behind the WAN IP of router 2

Comment: @Ron I was able to accomplish the same using port forwarding on a ubuntu machine with IP 192.168.0.x and forward to a proxy on 1.x series. 
The Ubuntu machine had multihoming setup, with 2 IP addresses one on each subnet.
However, without a proxy, it doesn't work

Comment: @Paul, How do I NAT everything, Mine is a dd-wrt, Netgear WNR2200
router. Added image showing NAT settings available in my router GUI.
Should I do it using IP tables on the router since I can do ssh.

Comment: That is port forwarding, Nat will be in the wan port settings probably

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what kind of router is this?
Sadly most (or many at least) consumer routers do not allow disabling NAT or routing on the LAN interface so the second segment will be doubly nat-ed (ugh).

Assuming you can and that the router1 allows routing on the lan side, you will HAVE TO touch router1, you need to at least tell router 1 to point to router 2 WAN to reach the second network.

Comment: Would RIP not allow auto propagation of the route?

Comment: yes of course, that's why I asked what kind of router are we talking about